# SQL login script fails, does nothing in PHP, gives an error in ideone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My SQL-Code for my Login-Script fails without an error. Under PHPMyAdmin it works perfectly, but under normal PHP it does not work. It uses a db.php which connects to a server. My Register.php works perfectly, when I manually edit the file it saves even a correct hash and so on, but it won't do anything with normal PHP.

With IDE One is it "Incomplete MYSQL".
http://ideone.com/19IQT4

```
SELECT `id` , `hash` , `salt` , `times`
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` LIKE 'Morten'
LIMIT 1
```

With PHPMyAdmin is the result:

```
id  hash                                 salt                                     times
1   8d59d4e2f8991af76621e2e9736243fb8c... 0cdf51838efb7d9fe89dd6fffdad4fdd03...     2
```

(It is correct) Under PHP comes:

```
db // Database Connect
1 // Negated output of mysql_query
FAIL // Did the Script fail?
```

And the Last: The PHP-Connect-Script:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "") or die("No Connection to Database!");
mysql_select_db("database");
```

PS: I have to use MySQL. The target server do not have MySQLi or PDO.
Here is the Loginscript:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
require 'functions.php';
session_start();
$username = $_POST["username"];
$passwort = $_POST["password"];
$abfrage = "SELECT `id`, `hash`, `salt`, `times` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE \'$username\' LIMIT 1 ;";
echo !mysql_query($abfrage);
if (!mysql_query($abfrage))
    die("FAIL");
$ergebnis=mysql_query($abfrage);
$row=mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($abfrage));
if(checkSaltedPass($passwort, $row->times, $row->hash, $row->salt)) {
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
    $_SESSION["uid"]=$row->id;
    $_SESSION["loginTimestamp"]=time();
} else {
    echo "FAIL ";
    print $username." ";
    print $abfrage." ";
    print $ergebnis." ";
    print $row." ";
}
?>
```

Comment: The server does not have mysqli or PDO but you connect on localhost?

Comment: You left the semicolon off of the ideone code: http://ideone.com/tOAwN9

Comment: Where's the login script code that is the problem?

Comment: The only problem is the MySQL-Code. It returns false.